# OpenOffice Compare two cell strings

Tags: macros, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, basic

So I am working on a macro in Basic, and where I'm at now I need to compare two columns for duplicates.

Here's what I have going so far:

```
for i = 0 To 5
   Cell1 = Sheet.getCellByPosition(0,i)

   for j = 0 to 5
   Cell2 = Sheet.getCellByPosition(1,j)

   rem COMPARISON WOULD HAPPEN HERE

   Next j
Next i
```

I would like to do something along the lines of: if Cell1.String == Cell2.String then ...

This is my first attempt at writing a macro and so I would greatly appreciate any help and/or guidance.

Thanks!

Also on a side note if anyone know of good tutorials.documentation for this other than wiki, I would be extremely grateful for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store all values of the first column into an array and then compare every value of the second column with all entries of the array using a simple recursion.

A code that may work is

```
Dim firstcolumn(5) As String

For i = 0 to 5
   firstcolumn(i) = Sheet.getCellByPosition(0,i)
Next i

For j = 0 to 5
   Cell2 = Sheet.getCellByPosition(1,j)
   for i = 0 to 5
    if Cell2 = firstcolumn(i) then
        MsgBox("The value of the cell " + i + " in the first column is the same with the value of the cell " + j + " of the second column")
    Next i   
Next j
```

The best place to look for code samples is the openoffice forum https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/

I hope that the above will help you.